# ASP.NET MVC 4 templates in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We are starting a new ASP.NET MVC project. The web application will be used also in a touch pad devices and therefore I am interested on ASP.NET MVC 4 Default Templates as it has feature called Adaptive Rendering and overall it seems to better starting point.

ASP.NET MVC 4 isn't yet ready for the production use, so I was thinking of using only parts of it.

Would the View side of the MVC 4 project (Layout, CSS, JavaScript) work on MVC 3 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does. They are all heavily **CSS3** and **Html5**. So you need to think about browser support rather than MVC runtime dlls.

I encourage you to check the below video out. It is just for you :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-796T